# Getting Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException when creating topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am new to Kafka, have started learning on my own.
I am trying to create a topic in Kafka, my zookeeper is running but every time I am getting below error.

[image]

Comment: Check the output of below commad: bin/zookeeper-shell 192.168.0.1:2181 ls /brokers/ids

Comment: Getting below error- 
E:\kafka_2.12-2.2.0>zookeeper-shell 192.168.0.1:2181 ls /brokers/ids
Connecting to 192.168.0.1:2181
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/ids
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1541)

Answer (score 0):

This means your zookeeper instance(s) are not running good.
Please check zookeeper log files for any error. By default zookeeper logs are stored under server.log file

Comment: Yes seems there is some issue in zookeeper only.    Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election

Comment: Can you please provide your zookeeper.properties file

Comment: There are only 3 entries as below-                                                                                 dataDir=E:/kafka_2.12-2.2.0/data/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0